# When do ROC-Curves intersect?

Tags: classification, roc, auc

In books I see ROC curves like this:

[image]

So I always think the model with the highest AUC is better at any threshold. Is this true in general?

When applying usual classification models, can there be two models for the same classification problem like this, where the first one has a higher AUC, but the second one is better for some applications?

[image]